# How to solve ImportError: No module named exceptions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I want to apply one of ensemble methods, majority voting, on my data. I also installed "mlxtend" through "pip install mlxtend". I am still getting the error. The following is the error that i get.

First here is the code:

```
from mlxtend.classifier import EnsembleVoteClassifier
mv_clf = MajorityVoteClassifier(classifiers=[pipe1, clf2, pipe3])
clf_labels += ['Majority Voting']
all_clf = [pipe1, clf2, pipe3, mv_clf]
for clf, label in zip(all_clf, clf_labels):
    scores = cross_val_score(estimator=clf,
    X=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    cv=10,
    scoring='roc_auc')
    print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f) [%s]"% (scores.mean(), scores.std(), label))
```

Noted i defined clf1, clf2 and clf3 before and that part is totally **fine**.

Here is the Error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9221440c28e1> in <module>()
----> 1 from mlxtend.classifier import EnsembleVoteClassifier
      2 import copy
      3 mv_clf = MajorityVoteClassifier(classifiers=[pipe1, clf2, pipe3])
      4 clf_labels += ['Majority Voting']
      5 all_clf = [pipe1, clf2, pipe3, mv_clf]

  10 from .softmax_regression import SoftmaxRegression
     11 from .multilayerperceptron import MultiLayerPerceptron
---> 12 from .ensemble_vote import EnsembleVoteClassifier
     13 from .stacking_classification import StackingClassifier
     14 from .stacking_cv_classification import StackingCVClassifier

     14 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
     15 from sklearn.base import clone
---> 16 from sklearn.exceptions import NotFittedError
     17 from ..externals.name_estimators import _name_estimators
     18 from ..externals import six
```

ImportError: No module named exceptions

**UPDATE**:After updating scikit learn version this is the error that i am getting

```
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-9643a2b164d6> in <module>()
      1 from mlxtend.classifier import EnsembleVoteClassifier
      2 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, VotingClassifier
----> 3 mv_clf = MajorityVoteClassifier(classifiers=[pipe1, clf2, pipe3])
      4 
      5 

NameError: name 'MajorityVoteClassifier' is not defined
```

Comment: Which versions of `sklearn` and `mlxtend` are you using?

Comment: @Aurora0001sklearn: 0.17.1  mlxtend: 0.5.1

Comment: You have imported `EnsembleVoteClassifier` but calling `MajorityVoteClassifier`. Have you imported it? From which library?

Comment: @VivekKumar unfortunately it seems there is no library for MajorityVoteClassifier anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The `sklearn.exceptions` module was [introduced in version 0.18.0](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6968) of `sklearn`. You need only upgrade your installation to the latest version (0.18.1 at the time of writing):

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

If you installed through via Anaconda, use:

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.18.1
```

This should resolve the issue and allow you to use the `sklearn.exceptions` module.

Comment: @Aurura0001 Now it gives me another error. NameError: name 'MajorityVoteClassifier' is not defined

Comment: @user8034918 I think that's a typo... Did you mean `EnsembleVoteClassifier`? That's what you import.

Comment: @user8034918 From the example you provide, you never import `MajorityVoteClassifier`, and I couldn't find it in either of the libraries you're using. Are you **sure** you mean `MajorityVoteClassifier`?

Comment: I want to use majorityVote classifier but i couldn't find any library in python to call the majority vote function!!! That's the problem.

Comment: @user8034918 What I'm saying is that the `MajorityVoteClassifier` **doesn't exist**. You can't use a class which doesn't exist in any of the libraries. Where did you read that you specifically needed `MajorityVoteClassifier`?